# What did it mean to be a Grecian in late-18th Century British schools?

Tags: 18th-century, education, great-britain

Near the beginning of CS Forester's novel [Mr Midshipman Hornblower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Midshipman_Hornblower), which begins in 1793, the titular Hornblower arrives on board his first ship, where the captain asks about his schooling:

> "How far did your education go?"
>
> "I was a Grecian at school, sir."
>
> "So you can construe Xenophon as well as Cicero?"
>
> "Yes, sir. But not very well, sir."
>
> "Better if you knew something about sines and cosines. Better if you could foresee a squall in time to get t'gallants in. We have no use for ablative absolutes in the Navy."

From the context it appears that to be a Grecian didn't only mean that he had learnt ancient Greek, but was also a shorthand for a specific level of educational attainment, in the same way as we might talk nowadays about people being a sixth form student.

Hornblower is only 17 at the time of this exchange, so it must be something pre-university, but I cannot find any more information to suggest what being a Grecian actually meant in the late 18th century in England.

Comment: Re being only 17, British (and other) universities were not so age-obsessed then as they are in the modern day.  Apparently students could be admitted even younger than 14, per the answer to this question: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/41469/how-did-people-apply-for-university-in-the-18th-century?rq=1

Comment: @jamesqf Cambridge, at least, still has policies and arrangements in place for students under 16.

Comment: @user3482749: But how often are they used?  Seldom enough, I think, that the occasional university student under 18 is newsworthy.

Comment: @jamesqf Under 18? Certainly not. In particular, it is extremely common for students from Scotland to start university at 17. Under 16 is much rarer, but still by no means newsworthy, except perhaps in the local papers of some very small village that such a student might come from.

Comment: Yes indeed, I appreciate that he could have gone to university at 17, but it seems extremely unlikely that he would have finished university and gone to sea by 17 without the novelist mentioning it.

Comment: I would say the context suggests precisely that to be a Grecian did mean that he had learnt ancient Greek.

Comment: Yes - the comment about Xenophon clearly indicates that to my mind, but I was asking if it didn't _only_ mean that he'd learnt ancient Greek.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the 1928 OED:

> **Grecian**:
> ....
> 2. One learned in the Greek language; a Greek scholar. [Attestations omitted]
> b. A boy in the highest class of Christ's Hospital (the Blue-coat school).

> **Blue-Coat**:
>
> 1. Formerly the dress of servants and the lower orders; hence of almoners and charity children. [Attestations omitted]
> 2. ....
> 3. (More fully, *Blue-coat* boy): A scholar of a charity school wearing the almoners blue coat. Of these there are many in England; the most noted being Christ's Hospital in London, whose uniform is a long dark blue gown fastened at the waist with a belt, and bright yellow stockings.

So Hornblower has completed his grammar school education as a charity scholarship student. He seems to be dissembling slightly on his charity status, without making an outright deception.

**Context**

An 18th (and even 19th) Century *liberal arts* education revolved around the seven traditional *liberal arts*, composed of:

- Trivium:
  -- Grammar (both Latin and Greek; reading, writing, and speaking);
  -- Logic
  -- Rhetoric;
- Quadrivium:
  -- Geometry;
  -- Arithmetic (in the Euclidean sense - so Number Theory);
  -- Music;
  -- Astronomy.

The *Trivium* was taught in a *grammar school* and was typically required as prerequisite to university admittance. Completion of the *Grammar* requirement (at this time) meant the capability of not only reading and writing Latin and Greek, but also of conversing in both to a moderate fluency.

The *sines and cosines* might have been introduced earlier at a trade school; but would not have been seen formally by Hornblower until reaching university and studying the Geometry and Arithmetic (ie Number Theory) of Euclid's Elements, as well as their practical application in *Astronomy* (probably physics by this period).

**Update**

1. It's not *canon* unless it's in the books.
2. You think an education at Eton, or even a lesser English *public school*, is comparable in cost to purchasing a midshipman's commission in His Majesty's Royal Navy in 1793? Seriously? I doubt the cost of a midshipman's commission would have purchased even a single term at any public school half as notable as Christ's Hospital. Further, *charity*  also includes *scholarship* and *bursary* students.

---

P.S.

If that Christ's Hospital uniform reminds you also of Harry Potter - I doubt that's just coincidence. Recall tha all wizard children in the United Kingdom were entitled to an education at Hogwart's - regardless of family financial means.

Comment: In the TV miniseries, Captain Pellew speaks of Hornblower "repaying the debt you owe your father" which implies Hornblower Sr. purchased his son's commission, which implies he had sufficient means to do so. So I'm not convinced HH had "charity status" as opposed to just a non-aristocratic upbringing.

Comment: @Spencer: 1) It's not *canon* unless it's in the books. 2) You think an education at Eton, or even a lesser English *public school*, is comparable in cost to purchasing a midshipman's commission in His Majesty's Royal Navy in 1793? Seriously? I doubt the cost of a midshipman's commission would have purchased even a single term at any public school half as notable as Christ's Hospital. Further, *charity*
 also includes *scholarship* and *bursary* students.

Comment: You edited your comment in verbatim?  Seriously, I wouldn't know the first thing about what the cost of a commision would be, relative to a public school education. But it can't be trivial, or everyone would be a naval officer.  You added useful clarifications, but it's probably a good idea to reduce that edit to just the bare facts and remove the ad hominem.

Comment: @Spencer: The *Lieutenants' Exam* made the Royal Navy a very strict meritocracy. Only those boys who were thought capable of passing it would have been commissioned as midshipmen - in point of fact there were more midshipmen from the professional classes than from the aristocracy for just that reason. The aristocratic dullards purchased commissions in the cavalry instead.

Comment: Hornblower notes, I think in the same story, that his father was the local doctor, adn that he had to show deference to the local Squire's son. He was also, IIRC, a *Kings Letter Boy*, which means that he was, unusually for that time, appointed a midshipman without being chosen by his captain. Midshipmen were typically appointed (not commissioned) by the Captain. This was more likely to be a favor to a friend or patron than a straight purchase, but could be for whatever reason the Captain chose. Only when becomming a Lieutenant, after passing the exam, was an officer commissioned.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: Thank you. It's been decades since I read the books, and I no longer own them. Can you possibly dig up quotes for those remarks?

Comment: @ Pieter Geerkens I'll take a look

Comment: Project Gutenberg has a copy of Mr Midshipman Hornblower here:
https://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/forestercs-mrmidshipmanhornblower/forestercs-mrmidshipmanhornblower-00-h.html

Comment: Also he must have started on the Quadrivium - or the geometry and arithmetic sections of it at least - almost the next sentence after those quoted says that "his mathematical studies were far advanced".

Comment: It might be of interest to note that Christ's Hospital school still has its Tudor uniform as standard wear for students (although I think the Doc Martens a lot of students wear are probably a more recent development). Christ's Hospital also still has a naval connection even today. https://images.app.goo.gl/vYLzYrZTSbrRo1Bs8